# How can i set The text of my Table View, via an NSArray, when im also using a Custom table View Cell?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, ios4

I have a UITable View that is being designed via a custom table view cell. I want the text to be different on every cell, so I added a `label` to my CustomCell, and hooked up an `IBOutlet` to it, but I'm having a very hard time wrapping my head around the logic part of the code. I have this so far:

// THIS IS IN MY TABLE VIEW CONTROLLER CLASS.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *object = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"TableOfContentsCell" owner:self options:nil];
        
        for (id currentObject in object) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
                
            cell = (TableOfContentsCell *)currentObject;
            break;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    //cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    
    // Configure the cell...
    
    return cell;
}


//This is in my Custom Table View Cell Class.

-(void)setTableText{
cellLabel.text = [table.tableCellText objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

I cannot figure out how to set the text when the text I want, is inside of an array!

Comment: you can declare your method like : -(void)setTableText:(id)sender  where you can pass an integer value to the method and call your array like: [yourArray objectAtIndex:sender];

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear why you want to load your data to the label in your custom cell, please clarify.
Secondly below the comment configure cell you can customize your cell. as you have done to set the textColor.
Just declare that array in your TABLE VIEW CONTROLLER CLASS

Then write the code below:

```
    // Configure the cell...
    
    cell.cellLabel.text = [yourArrayName objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just populate it from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    // Configure the cell...
    cellLabel.text = [table.tableCellText objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Just make sure that the tableview has access to table.tableCellText.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a seperate method .In your code in qn there is two lines commented ...( // Configure the cell...)
add this code to tht section

suppose you have two labels in your custom cell
then add tags to them (here as 1 and 2) and get its reference in code  by viewwithtag: method

```
UILabel *label=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
[label setText:@"2"];

UILabel *label2=(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
[label2 setText:@"sasd"];
```

The condition you have to keep is that the contents of cell must be tagged uniquely and using this method you can get reference of any view in your custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

Create your Custom cell class according to your need. then.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

 TableCustomCell *cell = (TableCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

//.....................

cell.yourLabel.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
```